# How to draw a triangle in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How to draw triangles in SQL Server as shown below?

[image]

I want to implement it by using `WHILE` loops, but I am unable to print 20 '*' in a single line in SQL Server.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why use *any* loop? SQL doesn't need loops. All you need is a way to generate a sequence from 1 to 20, provided you don't already have a Numbers table

Comment: You might be looking for the [`REPLICATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql) function

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Sounds like some sort of school assignment to me..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use **REPLICATE** inside a WHILE. I think, you can achieve your desired output if you do it correctly?

```
DECLARE @i INT = 20

WHILE(@i>0)
BEGIN
   PRINT REPLICATE('* ', @i);
   SET @i = @i - 1;
END
```

Comment: Using any kind of loop in SQL is a bad idea, even if it's just to solve a puzzle.

Comment: while this is just good programming question.Habiba script is good.Also in real life scenario there are situation where you can't avoid loop or cursor then there is no harm in using it.

Comment: @KumarHarsh in real life, you can always avoid loops and cursors. The cases where you need a loop are extremely rare. In almost every case a loop is harder, slower and causes a lot of blocking

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am aware about evil of cursor /loop/RBAR.BTW have you seen in build proc and function of sql server.in some example like this,its ok to use loop in order to enhance your skill.your script is also very ok

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Pragmatism aside, can you back up your assertion of loops being "harder, slower and causes a lot of blocking" *for this scenario*?

Comment: Yes. 2 lines instead of 6. Works just as fast for 20 or 2000 stars. Even more actually, but won't fit the screen. More importantly, can be used to generate data for other useful queries with minor modifications or even a simple join while the loop can't. Such puzzles exist to show you how to generate sequnces and range so you can solve *other* problems, like finding islands and gaps. Loops can't do that

Answer (score 8):

You can use `REPLICATE` to repeat a character a certain number of times. To generate a sequence of numbers from 1 to 20 you don't need a `WHILE` anyway - SQL doesn't really need the `WHILE` statement to work with data.

Number sequences are always useful which is why almost every SQL developer creates a [Numbers table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/).

If you don't already have one, a quick and dirty way to generate 20 numbers is to select the top 20 rows from a systems table, and use `ROW_NUMBER` to calculate row numbers eg:

```
select top 20 replicate('*',21-row_number() over (order by id) )
from sys.sysobjects
```

With a Numbers table, the query is simpler:

```
select replicate('*',Number )
from dbo.Numbers
where Numbers.Number <= 20
order by Number desc
```

Numbers tables are extremely useful, eg for sets of elements like 200 days starting from 2017/1/1 :

```
select dateadd(d,Number,cast('20170101' as date))
from dbo.Numbers
where Numbers.n<= 20
order by Number desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This,

```
DECLARE @StrLen INT = 20

WHILE @StrLen >= 1
BEGIN
    PRINT REPLICATE('*',@StrLen)
    SET @StrLen = @StrLen - 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without replicate() solution**

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @i int = 20
DECLARE @j int
DECLARE @line varchar(max)

        WHILE @i > 0

        BEGIN
            SET @line = ''
            SET @j = 0
                WHILE @j < @i
                BEGIN
                    SET @line +=  '* '
                    SET @j = @j + 1
                END
                PRINT @line
            SET @i = @i - 1

        END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Using recursive CTE (Press Ctrl+T for results in text)

```
;WITH A AS (
        SELECT REPLICATE('* ', 20) X
    UNION ALL
        SELECT LEFT(X, LEN(X) - 2)
        FROM A
        WHERE X > '* '
    )
SELECT * FROM A
```

Another way:

```
;WITH A AS (
        SELECT 20 X
    UNION ALL
        SELECT X - 1 FROM A
        WHERE X > 1
    )
SELECT REPLICATE('* ', X) FROM A
```