# How do I make a triangle of stars using stored procedures in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I would like to further exercise myself on the use of SQL stored procedures, so I thought of the following interesting problem.

How can I create a stored procedure with input to make a triangle of stars? For example input = 5 will print this:

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

I know this could be easily done without stored procedure, but my question is how can I make a stored procedure to make that? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Thanks Suraj, that one is done without using stored procedure (I know this should be fairly easy without using SP), but I am wondering how can I achieve this by using the stored procedure with inputs.

Comment: A way to draw the triangle in SSMS is using the `geometry` type: `SELECT geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 2))', 0) AS triangle;`. The spatial results will show the results graphically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the following stored procedure.

```
create procedure DrawTriangle
@StrLen INT 
as
Begin
 WHILE @StrLen >= 1
 BEGIN
     PRINT REPLICATE('*',@StrLen)
     SET @StrLen = @StrLen - 1
 END
END
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e6553e7e73eabf69a2010e238d6541a1) demo.

For more follow this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656703/how-to-draw-a-triangle-in-sql-server)

To print the triangle right-aligned you can use the below code.

```
create procedure DrawRightAlignedTriangle
@StrLen INT 
as
Begin
declare @i int = 0
declare @space int

 WHILE @StrLen >= 1
 BEGIN
     SET @space = @StrLen - @i 

     PRINT space(@i) + REPLICATE('*', @StrLen)
     SET @StrLen = @StrLen - 1
     SET @i = @i + 1
 END
END
```

Below is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc50ace5352e3b4d23ea07288d656e35) demo.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! And how can I make it right aligned?

Comment: @Kay Please check the updated answer for printing the right aligned triangle. I hope it will help you and if so request you to accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a `select`, using a recursive CTE:

```
with stars as (
      select replicate('*', 5) as stars
      union all
      select stuff(stars, 1, 1, '')
      from stars s
      where s.stars > ''
     )
select *
from stars s
order by s.stars desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dd32d4cb3554ffb90006b5e7469fd75c) is a db<>fiddle.

You can right align the starts on output, if you like:

```
with stars as (
      select replicate('*', 5) as stars
      union all
      select stuff(stars, 1, 1, '')
      from stars s
      where s.stars > ''
     )
select right(replicate(' ', 5) + s.stars, 5)
from stars s
order by s.stars desc;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make it right-aligned? Thanks.